# Value not usable in constant expression C++

Tags: c++

The following code is in C++ I am encountering the error of value is not usable in a constant expression error

---

```
int sumNumbers(TreeNode* root) {

    stack<pair<TreeNode*, int>> st;
    st.push(make_pair(root, root->val));
    int sum = 0;

    while(!st.empty()){
        pair<TreeNode*, int> temp = st.top();
        st.pop();
        TreeNode* node = temp.first;
        int value = temp.second;

        if(node->left==NULL && node->right==NULL){
            sum += value;
        }

        if(node->left){
            st.push(pair< node->left, value*10 + node->left->val >);
        }

        if(node->right){
            st.push(pair< node->right, value*10 + node->right->val >);
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

---

The error is in the line:

```
if(node->left){
            st.push(pair< node->left, value*10 + node->left->val >);
        }
```

---

The error is:

> Line 29: Char 37: error: the value of 'node' is not usable in a constant expression
>                    st.push(pair< node->left, value*10 + node->left->val >);

---

I am not able to figure out why this error is encountered here?

Comment: Use `make_pair()`

Comment: Readability suggestion :  `if(auto nl = node->left) { st.push(make_pair< nl, value*10 + nl->val >); `. An `if` statement may define a local variable for the value being compared.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use `make_pair` instead to create an object, setting the template types automatically:

```
st.push(make_pair(node->left, value*10 + node->left->val));
```

And same for the right side.

Comment: Alternatively, just use [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization): `st.push({node->left, value*10 + node->left->val})`